# How to render a 3D object to HTML file by using pythonOCC in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pythonocc

I have a Django application and I'm using pythonOCC package in it. I have to display the 3D .stl, .stp, .igs files in my template. Normally, when I call the render() function, the following outputs appear on my vscode console and since flask app created by pythonocc instead of django starts running in localhost, my index.html is never rendered. However I need to display the files in a Django template. That's why I have extended the [X3DomRenderer Class](https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core/blob/master/src/Display/WebGl/x3dom_renderer.py) such as below.

**My custom X3DomRenderer class:**

```
class CustomX3DomRenderer(x3dom_renderer.X3DomRenderer):
    def render_to_string(self):
        self.generate_html_file(self._axes_plane, self._axes_plane_zoom_factor)
        return open(self._html_filename, 'r').read()
```

**the HTML codes that returned from render_to_string() function:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>pythonOCC 7.4.0 x3dom renderer</title>
    <meta name='Author' content='Thomas Paviot - tpaviot@gmail.com'>
    <meta name='Keywords' content='WebGl,pythonOCC'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://x3dom.org/release/x3dom.css">
    <script src="https://x3dom.org/release/x3dom.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            background: linear-gradient(#ced7de, #808080);
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #pythonocc_rocks {
            padding: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 1%;
            bottom: 2%;
            height: 38px;
            width: 280px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 2px solid #f7941e;
            opacity: 0.7;
            font-family: Arial;
            background-color: #414042;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 14px;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        #commands {
            padding: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 1%;
            top: 2%;
            height: 65px;
            width: 180px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 2px solid #f7941e;
            opacity: 0.7;
            font-family: Arial;
            background-color: #414042;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 14px;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        a {
            color: #f7941e;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a:hover {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

        <x3d id="pythonocc-x3d-scene" style="width:100%;border: none" >
                <Scene>

            <transform scale="1,1,1">
            <transform id="plane_smallaxe_Id" rotation="1 0 0 -1.57079632679">
                <inline url="https://rawcdn.githack.com/x3dom/component-editor/master/static/x3d/plane.x3d" mapDEFToID="true" namespaceName="plane"></inline>
                <inline url="https://rawcdn.githack.com/x3dom/component-editor/master/static/x3d/axesSmall.x3d" mapDEFToID="true" namespaceName="axesSmall"></inline>
            </transform>
            <inline url="https://rawcdn.githack.com/x3dom/component-editor/master/static/x3d/axes.x3d" mapDEFToID="true" namespaceName="axes"></inline>
            </transform>
            <transform id="glbal_scene_rotation_Id" rotation="1 0 0 -1.57079632679">                    <Inline onload="fitCamera()" mapDEFToID="true" url="shp6b8ef6d6e61744489de16a6798cfe998.x3d"></Inline>
</transform>            </Scene>
        </x3d>

    <div id="pythonocc_rocks">
        pythonocc-7.4.0 <a href="https://www.x3dom.org" target="_blank">x3dom</a> renderer
        <br>Check our blog at
        <a href=http://www.pythonocc.org>http://www.pythonocc.org</a>
    </div>
    <div id="commands">
    <b>t</b> view/hide shape<br>
    <b>r</b> reset view<br>
    <b>a</b> show all<br>
    <b>u</b> upright<br>
    </div>
    <script>
    var selected_target_color = null;
    var current_selected_shape = null;
    var current_mat = null;
    function fitCamera()
    {
        var x3dElem = document.getElementById('pythonocc-x3d-scene');
        x3dElem.runtime.fitAll();
    }
    function select(the_shape) // called whenever a shape is clicked
    {
        // restore color for previous selected shape
        if (current_mat) {
            current_mat.diffuseColor = selected_target_color;
        }
        // store the shape for future process
        current_selected_shape = the_shape;
        console.log(the_shape);
        // store color, to be restored later
        appear = current_selected_shape.getElementsByTagName("Appearance")[0];
        mat = appear.getElementsByTagName("Material")[0];
        current_mat = mat;
        console.log(mat);
        selected_target_color = mat.diffuseColor;
        mat.diffuseColor = "1, 0.65, 0";
        //console.log(the_shape.getElementsByTagName("Appearance"));//.getAttribute('diffuseColor'));
    }
    function onDocumentKeyPress(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (event.key=="t") {  // t key
         if (current_selected_shape) {
           if (current_selected_shape.render == "true") {
              current_selected_shape.render = "false";
           }
           else {
              current_selected_shape.render = "true";
           }
         }
      }

    }
    // add events
    document.addEventListener('keypress', onDocumentKeyPress, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**and here is my view:**

```
def occ_viewer(request):
    shape = read_step_file(os.path.join('C:/Users/imgea/desktop/bgtask/bgtask/ThreeDFile', 'splinecage.stp'))
    my_renderer = extend_x3dom.CustomX3DomRenderer(path='C:/Users/imgea/desktop/bgtask/bgtask/ThreeDFile')
    my_renderer.DisplayShape(shape)
    context = {'viewer': my_renderer.render_to_string()}
    return render(request, 'success.html', context)
```

and I have added these HTML codes that I got from `render_to_string()` function to my template file. The viewer's grid has shown but the 3D object hasn't because of the error below.

```
Page not found: http://127.0.0.1:8000/file/occview/shp6b8ef6d6e61744489de16a6798cfe998.x3d
```

The library creates that .x3d file in the same directory with the file that I wanna render to template but I guess the viewer is looking for this .x3d file in the error which I mentioned before even I sent the directory. I couldn't find the cause of this error. Am I missing something?

Thank you!!